# bind to already running Service

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, service

Heres my problem:
I am implementing a music player (PlayerActivity.java / xml) which is bound to a service (PlayerService.java) that basically is just an instance of a musicplayer so that it can run in the background. When lefting the app or changing the activity and the restarting the activity i want to bind to the still running service without stopping or restarting it. I have tried using only bindService() but that made me face the problem: somehow without calling startService() before bindService the Service doesn't get initialized or it takes a few milliseconds so that the functions only get null when accessing service functions.
Here is my service class:

```
public class playerService extends Service {

    public boolean running = false;

    public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    public boolean isPrepared = false;
    private String url;

    public class serviceBinder extends Binder {
        public playerService getService() {
            return playerService.this;
        }
    }

    public boolean isRunning(){
        return running;
    }

    private IBinder mBinder = new serviceBinder();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.w("Service", "started");
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        running = true;
        Log.e("!!!", running + "");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void pause() {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    public void resume() {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void setupPlayer() {
        try {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MediaPlayer", e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MediaPlayerToo", e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void reset(){
        mediaPlayer.reset();
    }

    public void updateUrl(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void start(){
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public int getCurrentPosition(){
        return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    public int getDuration(){
        return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
    }

}
```

I experimented with waiting until the Service has started with a boolean. But when i add any kind of code
after

```
mService = binder.getService();
startService(intent);
```

it seems to not get created at all.

Here is also my onServiceConnected class

```
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            playerService.serviceBinder binder = (playerService.serviceBinder) service;
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), playerService.class);
            mService = binder.getService();
            startService(intent);
            //... <- adding code here will result in the Service not starting?!!

        }
```

I know that my problem is quite confusing, but this was the best i could come up explaining it. I would be really glad if you had any idea because this problem stops me from deployment. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Requests to bind (or start) a service are posted on main looper, calling `startService` will not call `onStartCommand` immediately. Just move your player initialization logic to services `onCreate` which will be called regardless if service is created due to bind or start.

Comment: Thanks! You helped me really much here.